# Window forwarding to laptop from workstation

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-10.04, xorg, x11-forwarding

At home I have my desktop computer and loads of open windows. When I decide to work outside or in another room with my laptop. I'd like to select a few windows and just make them appear on the laptop. They should be directly attached to the ones at the main computer. I don't want my entire desktop, like VNC, but something like X11 forwarding over SSH. The SSH thing sounds wonderful but moving an existing window seems to be a hard task.

I've read about FreeNX but I want to know if there is a simple way, and if FreeNX even does what I want. I've seen feature lists saying "seamless windows", but no screenshots proving that.

Both computers run Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

With X forwarding you can only open new windows, not connect to the existing. FreeNX is more less the same as VNC, so it won't help either. So I believe the answer for now is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

[xmx](http://www.cs.brown.edu/software/xmx/) and [guievict](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zandy/guievict/) both claim to be able to do this, but they haven't been maintained for a while.

Comment: +1 for excavating; still I think xmx is not a case.